# Why the image of a linear map is not always a Banach space?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have a question: Let's think about the map $T:V \rightarrow \text{ran}(T)$ and $V$ be a Banach space. Then we have that this is the same as the quotient map $[T]:V \rightarrow V/\ker(T)$ where the latter space is also a Banach space and an isomorphism $\hat{T}:V/\ker(T) \rightarrow \text{ran}(T)$. This one is injective as we factored out the nullspace and surjective by definition of the image. But this would suggest that the image is always a Banach space? So where am I wrong?

Comment: It's an isomorphism only as far as the vector space structure is concerned, not generally if we take the topology into account. A continuous bijection need not be a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer but isn't this exactly what the open mapping theorem says?

Comment: No, for the open mapping theorem, you need that the range is a Banach space as a premise. That is essential for the conclusion [there are generalisations, the OMT holds for a much larger class than Banach spaces, but if we only look at normed spaces, it's Banach or bust]. If $X$ is a Banach space, $Y$ a normed space, and $T\colon X\to Y$ a continuous linear bijection, then $T^{-1}$ is continuous _if and only if_ $Y$ is a Banach space.

Comment: ah you are right, so I kind of proved my premise ;-). thank you.

Comment: "Banach or bust" sounds like a functional analyst's version of "(Aut) Caesar aut nihil".

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example. $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, the Hilbert space (and thus Banach space as well) of all square summable sequences, i.e., $a=(a_n)$, with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2<\infty$, and define $T:H\to H$ as
$$
T(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,\ldots)=\left(\frac{a_1}{1},\frac{a_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{a_n}{n},\ldots\right)
$$
Clearly 
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\ldots,\frac{1}{n},\ldots\right)\not\in \mathrm{Range}(T),
$$
as $(1,1,\ldots,1,\ldots)\not\in H$. BUT
$$
b_1=(1,0,0,0,\ldots), \,b_2=(1,\tfrac{1}{2},0,0,\ldots), \,b_3=(1,\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{3},0,0,\ldots),\ldots
\in \mathrm{Range}(T),
$$
and $\lim b_n=\left(\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\ldots,\frac{1}{n},\ldots\right)\not\in \mathrm{Range}(T)$.

Hence $\mathrm{Range}(T)$ is not complete.

This in fact is the case when $T$ is a compact operator.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence: It is the case when $T$ is a compact operator with infinite dimensional range.  A finite rank operator has complete range.

Comment: This is correct.